# Building reusable components with gtk glade

Tags: python, pygtk, glade, reusability

I am writing a simple application and am using glade (gtk) for the UI. I need many windows (~10), of which one will open depending upon the command line flags, other contextual stuff etc.

Now, all these windows are pretty much similar, they have 3 top level tabs, the last tab is the same in all, all have a `OK` and `Quit` button etc., so I am looking for a way to build these windows in glade. I could copy paste one window and make the changes in that, but I am looking for a better way, that will allow me to reuse the common parts of the windows.

Also, I am using pygtk for loading up the windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design a widget with the common aspects you mention. Wherever you need to implement something different, put a GtkAlignment with an appropriate name. Don't forget to change the alignment and fill values of the GtkAlignment.

In PyGTK you can [gtk.Builder.get_object(name)](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkbuilder.html#method-gtkbuilder--get-object) to get access to these empty regions and add the extra components within them (which can also be designed with Glade).

Comment: How do I design the extra components to add to `GtkAlignment`, I need a top level window or something to design anything. Should I design a dummy window and get the component object from that window with `.get_object` and add it to the `GtkAlignment`?

Comment: @Shrikant Sharat - Right click on the button for whatever widget you want as the top level one, and a menu should come up with an item "Add widget as toplevel". Click that, and you're done :) Hardly intuitive, I know, but it's there.

Comment: @detly, thanks, but I don't see that option. I am using an older version of glade (3.6.7). Its what the ubuntu repos offer :). However, for anyone else coming across, your solution makes more sense, so am marking it.

Comment: @Shrikant - there may be another way, I'll do some research.

Comment: @Shrikant - I'm using 3.6.7 too. If I right click on the button to add a `GtkAlignment`, there's a popup menu with a single item: "Add widget as toplevel". You say you don't see it?

Comment: Ack, (slaps head) I was right clicking the component I want as top level, in the editor pane, not the button on the left. I got it now, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with the help of detly's answer, I am able to get something working. For anyone who needs it, here is what I did.

main.glade contains the window and all the common cruft that I need to be displayed in all windows. comp.glade contains a window, with a vbox component with the extra stuff I need, lets call it 'top_comp'.

Now, in main.glade, I put a gtk.Alignment component in the place where I need the extra component to load, and call it, say, 'comp_holder'. With the builder I have, I do

```
builder = gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file('main.glade'))
builder.add_from_file('comp.glade'))

builder.get_object('top_comp').reparent(builder.get_object('comp_holder'))
```

This method seems to work for now, but I don't know if it is the correct way to do this thing.

Any suggestions for the above welcome.

Comment: See my comment above for how to do this. I've done it so often I forgot how stupid the interface is for it :P